# How to find the timeline index of a keyframe_point by script?

Tags: animation, scripting

I know you can get the frame_range of an action, but regarding individual keyframe_points, what property signifies their place in the timeline?

Answer (score 0):

To find the frame number of a keyframe_point:

```
keyframePoint.co[0]
```